# What if one of control paths doesn't return a value?

Tags: c++, exception, compiler-errors, standards, compiler-warnings

```
int f(int n)
{
    if (n > 0) return 1;
}

int main()
{
    f(0); // Does the C++ standard see this as an error?
}
```

Another example:

```
int f()
{
    try
    { 
        return mayThrow();
    }  
    catch(...)
    {
        throw; // rethrow and no return. Is this conforming to the C++ standard?
    }
}

int main()
{
    f();
}
```

Third example:

```
int f()
{
    try
    { 
        throw 0;
    }  
    catch(...)
    {
        throw; // rethrow and no return. Is this conforming to the C++ standard?
    }
}

int main()
{
    f();
}
```

Comment: undefined behavior, and at compile time a warning or an error depending on the compiler and options :-)

Comment: I believe the first example is an Undefined Behavior the second is not.

Comment: @drescherjm Depends on whether or not `mayThrow()` does actually throw.

Comment: @walnut, what if `mayThrow()` does throw?

Comment: @xmllmx Then you are not flowing of the end of the function and everything is fine, see the answers in the linked duplicates.